# Have to switch furnace off twice to reset

Tags: hvac

My furnace inducer fan starts but the furnace does not fire, it is a Lennox Furnace installed in 2003. The LED lights indicate DS1 off DS2 Flashing. Changed the pressure switch out, checked inlet and exhaust vents, and still has the same problem. Have to turn the furnace off and on twice to get it to work. It will then run normally and may cut in and out properly for sometime before having to reset.

Best photo I could get of the control board:

[image: control board]

Comment: What model is the furnace?

Comment: Lennox G60uhv-36B-090-02

Comment: Can you provide us with photos of your control board? According to the [install manual for your furnace](https://www.questargas.com/ForEmployees/qgcOperationsTraining/Furnaces/Lennox_G60UHV_(X).pdf), you should have a control with 4 diagnostic LEDs on it, but only one (STATUS) is used for trouble codes though.

Comment: Can you provide us with a model number of your control board? It looks to be an aftermarket replacement...

Comment: Lennox White Rodgers 18m9901. It is the original control board.

Comment: [This manual](https://climate.emerson.com/documents/21v51u-843-installation-instructions-en-us-1645268.pdf) should match your control board, then